# JetBrains dotCover: Coverage session finished with errors: Out of allowed iteration to generate unique temp name

Tags: c#, nunit, jetbrains-ide, dotcover

I generate a coverage report using dotCover.exe from the command line, but it randomly fails with this error:

```
[JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session finished with errors: Out of allowed iteration to generate unique temp name
  [location] = C:\Build Agent\work\f532b5455ffc19e9\Profiler\Kernel\Windows\Native\Solution\core\src\Util\temp_util.cpp(44)
  [function] = class boost::filesystem::path __cdecl jetbrains::profiler::temp::`anonymous-namespace'::create_temp<class jetbrains::profiler::temp::create_temp_file::<lambda_91d5f1a5933e4e60038be7ca777762a9>,0x010>(const class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &,class jetbrains::profiler::temp::create_temp_file::<lambda_91d5f1a5933e4e60038be7ca777762a9> &&)
  [file name] = C:\Temp\ft.EC76593C.tmp
  [WIN32 error] = 80, The file exists.
```

My command line looks like this:

```
dotCover.exe analyse /TargetExecutable=nunit3-console.exe /TargetArguments="unittest1.dll unittest2.dll ... unittest10.dll" /ReportType="html" /Output=CodeCoverage.html /Filters="+:*;-:*.*Tests;-:*.*.Tests;-:*.Tests;-:*.Tests*" /TempDir=C:\Temp\
```

It seems the more DLLs I try to cover the more likely it is to fail with this error. From the error message it seems dotCover is written in C++ and it's using `boost::filesystem::path` to create a temp file but there is some race condition and it tries to create a new temp file where it already exists. My dotCover version is `JetBrains dotCover Console Runner 2017.1.2. Build 108.0.20170428.80910`.

Does anyone have any idea what's how to fix that error?

**Edit:** There is another error with which it fails - `Access is denied`:

```
  [function] = class boost::filesystem::path __cdecl jetbrains::profiler::temp::`anonymous-namespace'::create_temp<class jetbrains::profiler::temp::create_temp_file::<lambda_91d5f1a5933e4e60038be7ca777762a9>,0x010>(const class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &,class jetbrains::profiler::temp::create_temp_file::<lambda_91d5f1a5933e4e60038be7ca777762a9> &&)
  [file name] = C:\Temp2\ft.0A96C261.tmp
  [WIN32 error] = 5, Access is denied.
```

Again, this happens randomly - usually it will fail 3 times and then run successfully on the 4th.

Comment: Have you tried reporting the issue to JetBrains using [their bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DOTP)?

Comment: looks loke a bug, this "0A96C261.tmp" looks like some encoded timestamp. maybe multiple test suites are trying to create  a temp file at the same time.

Comment: @jαsοndιnAlt Is this done by nunit? I know it can run tests in parallel, so maybe if I manage to convince it to serialize them (i.e. run them one after another) the problem will go away.

Comment: @SergGr Thanks, I found [an existing bug about it there](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PROF-641) - which did not appear in any results. It seems their bugtracker isn't being indexed by google. They claim it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @sashoalm they caim its in the [eap6](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/) version which is out now

Comment: @NtFreX Thanks I'll try testing it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

was running into this issue at times, using the early access version(JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.2017.2.20170630.95316-eap06) made it  disappear the issue till now.

> Looks like a bug in the dotcover tool opened [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PROF-641) .You can
>   download the latest version of **dotcover commandline tools** from
>   [here](https://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.2017.2.20170630.95316-eap06.zip)

**Edit:**

Get the latest version of dotcover from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/download/#section=commandline) as it has the issue resolved

Comment: Using the download link to 2017.2 eap6 is not a good idea any more. Use this link instead: https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/download/#section=commandline